# How to add Coupon Code Section In mini cart like in the shopping cart

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart, mini-cart

I have searched a lot on google but didn't get the solution for this.
I new to Magento, can any help me to how to add the coupon code section in Mini cart of magento.
Like the Below Example:
[image]

I have added this in items.phtml

```
<?php $getCouponCode = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getCouponCode(); ?>
                    <form id="discount-coupon-form" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/coupon')?>" method="post">
                    <!-- <label for="coupon_code"> <?php //echo $this->__('Enter your coupon code if you have one.') ?></label> -->
                    <input id="coupon_code" name="coupon_code" value="<?php echo $getCouponCode; ?>"/>
                    <?php  if(strlen($getCouponCode)) { ?>
                    <button type="button" onclick="updateminiCoupon(2); return false;" value="<?php echo $this->__('Remove Coupon')?>"><span><?php echo $this->__('Remove Coupon') ?></span></button>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <button type="button" onclick="updateminiCoupon(1); return false;" value="<?php echo $this->__('Apply Coupon')?>"><span><?php echo $this->__('Apply Coupon') ?></span></button>
                    </form>
```

and js :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function updateminiCoupon(reqid) {
    //alert('d');
    var reqid;
    if(reqid == 2) {  $('coupon_code').setValue('');  }
    $('discount-coupon-form').request({
        method: 'post',
        onComplete: payment.onComplete,
        onSuccess: payment.onSave,
        onFailure: checkout.ajaxFailure.bind(checkout),
    })
}
//]]>
</script>
```

by reference link:
http://www.endreywalder.com/blog/add-coupon-code-form-to-magento-onepage-checkout-review-step/

Check the Reference site : http://www.nykaa.com/

Comment: please see the screenshot http://prntscr.com/fb2rjh.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_coupon')->setTemplate('checkout/cart/coupon.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Please make use the above code and call the same in the file path

```
app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\checkout\cart\minicart.phtml
```

Note: i have used the default mangento 1.9.x with rwd theme 
[image]

And

[image]

Comment: Check the reference site link http://www.nykaa.com/

Comment: Same type of functionality i am trying to implement in my site

Comment: please find the screenshots here https://prnt.sc/fb2ul7
http://prntscr.com/fb2yrk

Comment: after applying the coupon code it will redirect to shopping cart.it must be remain in that page only through ajax

Comment: just keep this $this->_redirect('checkout/cart/'); code in your controller http://prntscr.com/fb35yh   after 'Coupon code "%s" was applied'  http://prntscr.com/fb36nv

Comment: if this code has been worked please test it from your end and accept my answer so that it will be useful for others thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59167/discussion-between-nagaraju-kasa-and-prashanth).

Comment: I tried the same in magento 2...https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/175660/coupon-block-not-displaying-inside-mini-cart   hope it may be of use ..dint try it in magento 1.9

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Ejassi products and they have exceeded my expectations! From skincare to fragrances, their range is exceptional. The quality and effectiveness are remarkable. I highly recommend checking out their website at [https://ejassi.com/] for a wide selection of top-notch products. You won't be disappointed!