# Coupon block not displaying inside mini cart

Tags: magento-2.1, css, coupon, mini-cart

I am trying to add coupon block in mini cart of magento.

But the coupon code block is displaying in the content section (also css changed!)

**\Magento\Checkout\view\frontend\layout\default.xml**

**UPDATED: To display the coupon block in the minicart**

```
 <referenceContainer name="minicart.addons">
        <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout::cart/coupon.phtml</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
      ...
```

Comment: There is a free extension available: https://marketplace.magento.com/ambab-module-slidingcart.html

Answer (score 2):

In the xml it's unlikely that a reference to `header-wrapper` is the one to use. Something could be added in `module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/minicart.phtml`.

I noticed `<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('minicart.addons'); ?>` in there, so maybe addons (like coupon) could be added from the back office.

If not then maybe you'll have to search in

`module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart.js`

or in `module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/discount-codes.js`

Hope these are some helpful research track.

Comment: oh cool buddy, i tried with referenceContainer name="minicart.addons"  and it worked :D thanks for the tip, except the 'Apply Discount Code' link doesnt appear as one... like how it appears on the checkout page

Comment: If it is a display issue, then maybe it's due to some css in `cart/coupon.phtml` , that isn't destined to be in mini-cart area, conflicting there. maybe you can provide some more details, cool !

Comment: @Sushivam hii! did you find solution for this? if yes please share here. i also want to display coupon code section in minicart.

Answer (score 1):

**You Can add this code in minicart.phtml**

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Coupon')->setTemplate('Magento_Checkout::cart/coupon.phtml')->toHtml();
```

But this has to be outside minicart-content-wrapper "div" else there will be css conflicts and Apply coupon code option won't work.